# How to Enter values into particular field in selenium if it is not an input tag

Tags: selenium, input

I have to enter values into the filed which is designed using UL tag.

I am able to click on it but could not able to send values.

Is anyone know the solution for this??

Comment: can you please provide your url ?

Comment: Can you share your UI structure? and what will be the value which you need to send? and what is your effort in code?

Comment: Without referring your HTML, No one can help you as it desire. Share the relevant HTML block.

Comment: error stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Robot Class in selenium**

- Robot Class can simulate Keyboard and Mouse Event
- Robot Class can help in upload/download of files when using selenium web driver
- Robot Class can easily be integrated with current automation framework (keyword, data-driven or hybrid)

e.g:

```
   Robot robot = new Robot();  // Robot class throws AWT Exception  
   Thread.sleep(2000); // Thread.sleep throws InterruptedException  
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
```

**Sendkey**

driver.findElement(By.xpath("locator")).sendKeys("value");